# Depth buffer in 2D

Tags: opengl, zbuffer, 2.5d

I'm working on a 2D game with realistic deferred lighting. Since I'm rendering the lights after the scene is rendered, I need a way to cull lighting calculations if there is an object, such as a tree, obstructing the area being lit. After doing some reading, my best bet for deferred rendering is to use a depth buffer. I've been searching the internet for ways to have a depth buffer with 2D graphics but really have not found anything helpful. I found `glPolygonOffset` but I really have no clue if that is what I want, or if there is another way to set a z value for the polygons. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your misconception lies in thinking "3D == perspective". To generate a depth buffer your scene needs, well, depth. But that's no problem. What you refer to as "2D" probably just means lack of perspective. So by using a ortho projection and placing your objects on layers at various depth you can generate a depth buffer with data usefull for deferred lighting.

Comment: By adjusting the z coordinate of the polygons?

Comment: What he means is, no matter what the z value, it does not change the appearance because there is no perspective. You can move things further into the screen or closer to the camera and it will look the same as long as it isn't too far in either direction.

Comment: And with "too far" that means outside the viewing clipping volume, of which the boundearies you can set. And unlike a perspective projection, in ortho projection the depth values depend on Z linearily.